# Indefinite Number Of Member Variables In A Class? C++

Tags: c++, class, random

For my GroupPicker program, I need to allow for `class group` to have an infinite number of slots for each of the numbers randomly generated that are assigned to each student entered.
The code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <time.h>

using namespace std;

class student
{
    int m_studentNumber;
public:
    string nameFirst;
    string nameLast;
    string nameFull;
    int getStudentNumber() { return m_studentNumber; }
    void setStudentNumber(int studentNumber) { m_studentNumber = studentNumber; }
};

class group
{
public:
};

ostream& operator<<(ostream& os, const student& s)
{
     return os << s.nameFirst << ' ' << s.nameLast;
}

student typeName()
{
    student bar;
    cout << "Type in a student's first name: ";
    cin >> bar.nameFirst;
    cout << "Type in that student's last name: ";
    cin >> bar.nameLast;
    cout << "\n";
    bar.nameFull = bar.nameFirst + " " + bar.nameLast;
    return bar;
}

void displayStudents(student listOfStudents[50], int studentHeadCount)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < studentHeadCount; i++)
    {
        cout << listOfStudents[i].nameFull << endl;
        cout << listOfStudents[i].getStudentNumber() << endl;
        cout << "\n";
    }
}

void options()
{

    cout << "Select what you want to do:\n";
    cout << "1) Exit application\n";
    cout << "2) Enter a Student\n";
    cout << "3) Display Students\n";
    cout << "4) Display Groups\n";
    cout << "5) Output groups as text file\n";
    cout << "\n";
}

int main()
{
    student allStudents[50]; // Having 50 students alone is ridiculous
    bool endProg = 0;
    int maxStudents;
    int studentsPerGroup;
    int optionSelect;
    int studentHeadCount = 0;
    int remainder;
    int numberOfGroups;
    cout << "GroupPicker 1.0\n";    
    cout << "How many students are in the class?\n" << "(Note: You cannot have more than 50 in this program)\n";
    cin >> maxStudents;
    if (maxStudents > 50)
    {
        cerr << "Too many students! Exiting program...\n";
        system("PAUSE");
        exit(1);
    }
    cout << "How many students per group?\n";
    cin >> studentsPerGroup;
    if (studentsPerGroup >= maxStudents)
    {
        cerr << "You're kidding, right?\n" << "Exiting program...\n";
        system("PAUSE");
        exit(1);
    }
    while (endProg == 0) {
        options();
        cin >> optionSelect;
        switch (optionSelect) {
            case 1:
                endProg = 1;
                break;
            case 2:
            {
                if (studentHeadCount == maxStudents)
                {
                    cerr << "You can't enter more than " << maxStudents << " students\n";
                }
                else
                {
                    allStudents[studentHeadCount] = typeName();
                    allStudents[studentHeadCount].setStudentNumber(studentHeadCount);
                    studentHeadCount++;
                }
                break;
            }
            case 3:
                cout << "Current list of students:\n\n";
                displayStudents(allStudents, studentHeadCount);
                break;
            case 4:
            {
                if (studentHeadCount < studentsPerGroup || studentHeadCount < maxStudents)
                {
                    cerr << "Invalid group parameters.\n" << "Returning to main menu...\n";
                    break;
                }
                else
                {
                cout << "Here are the groups:\n";
                numberOfGroups = maxStudents / studentsPerGroup;
                }
            }
            case 5:
            {
                cout << "Saving groups to file...\n";
                ofstream studentGroups;
                studentGroups.open("studentGroups.txt");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

How can I have an indefinite number of variables in the group class, depending on how many students there are per group?

Comment: It will probably be limited by the amount of memory on your system.

Comment: You would create an array or some other data structure such as a list or a vector.

Comment: Read about C++ standard [containers](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/), e.g.  [std::vector](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector)

Comment: @MikeChristensen Even so, the program cannot have more than 50 students. So it's not actually infinite.

Comment: @IlyaKogan Are you suggesting that I create a simple array or a multidimensional array?

Comment: @DJHead-On - Something that small, probably just use an array of 50.  For something truly dynamic, a linked list (or, as others have said, a vector)

Comment: `cerr << "You're kidding, right?\n";`

Comment: So infinite or 50? Quite a difference.

Comment: @m0skit0 Oh yeah, I should have made that clear. I actually meant indefinite.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You cannot have an "infinite" number, as you will be limited by available memory.  However, you **can** have a number that is not specified at compile-time.  Change your student array to a vector of students:

```
std::vector<student> allStudents;
```

Comment: Although I can do so, I would need a vector to have an undefined number of students per group. I purposely set the max number of students in the program to be 50.

Comment: @DJHead-On Perhaps we are not quite understanding your question then.  Are you asking how you can have an unspecified number of member variables within `group`?

Answer (score 1):

It appears you are looking for a data structure such as `std::vector<student>`.

Answer (score 1):

You do not actually need infinite number of students in each group. What you really need is a **indefinite** number of students in each group. For that, you can use any standard containers such as `std::vector<student>` or `std::list<student>` in your `group` class or replace the `group` class.